# Tensorflow not running on GPU in jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter, python-3.5

Installed Cuda and cudnn sucessfully for the GTX 1080 ti on Ubuntu, running a simple TF program in the jupyter notebook the speed does not increase in a conda environment running tensorflow-gpu==1.0 vs tensorflow==1.0.

When I run nvidia-smi :

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.66 Driver Version: 375.66 |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU Name Persistence-M| Bus-Id Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan Temp Perf Pwr:Usage/Cap| Memory-Usage | GPU-Util Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
| 0 GeForce GTX 108... Off | 0000:01:00.0 On | N/A |
| 24% 45C P0 62W / 250W | 537MiB / 11171MiB | 0% Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes: GPU Memory |
| GPU PID Type Process name Usage |
|=============================================================================|
| 0 1101 G /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg 310MiB |
| 0 1877 G compiz 219MiB |
| 0 3184 G /usr/lib/firefox/firefox 5MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried putting the "with tf.device("/gpu:0"):" in front of the matrix multiplications but it just gives me an error:

"InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device to node 'MatMul': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
[[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/device:GPU:0"](Reshape, softmax/Variable/read)]]"

I know cudnn is installed correctly because I get this message when running it in the terminal.

```
import tensorflow as tf
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
```

I think this has to be something with the Jupiter notebook, is there a compatibility issue? When I run the TF session I get this output:

```
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
Device mapping: no known devices.
```

"""

Answer (score 7):

I solved the issue. Apparently I had jupyter and regular tensorflow installed outside of my environment. Yet I had tensorflow-gpu installed within my environment. So when I ran jupyter it was calling the tensorflow outside of the environment not the tensorflow-gpu installed within the environment.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the meaning of this?  Is this referring specifically to the items on the Jupyter New dropdown list, where you can pick a conda environment, if so equipped?  "Apparently I had jupyter and regular tensorflow installed outside of my environment. Yet I had tensorflow-gpu installed within my environment. So when I ran jupyter it was calling the tensorflow outside of the environment not the tensorflow-gpu installed within the environment."

Comment: Are you saying you created a new jupyter notebook and selected "environ A" (for example), but your code actually ran in "environ B" some how?  Is that even possible?

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson: In my case, I had created a new environment (env A) with functioning tensorflow. However, an old tensorflow version was ALSO installed in the conda (base) environment. Somehow, when using jupyter notebook (env A) it tried to load the outdated tensorflow in base (with incompatible CUDA) and threw an error. I think this is what OP was talking about. I fixed it by uninstalling anaconda and re-installing.