# Can't run Tensorflow on GPU within jupyter-notebook

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, jupyter-notebook

I can't be able to run the tensorflow code with GPU when I ran it from a jupyter notebook. Same code runs no problem, if I ran in a python script.

I followed the main installation link:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

Also tried:

http://bailiwick.io/2017/11/05/tensorflow-gpu-windows-and-jupyter/

No problems outside notebook when I ran in a python script file.

Most likely the problem is similar to this:

[Tensorflow not running on GPU in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360763/tensorflow-not-running-on-gpu-in-jupyter-notebook)

More specifically my test:
[I can see both devices CPU and GPU via python a script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOJfe.jpg)

[I can see only CPU via notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBaUw.jpg)

Thanks a lot for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Very late, but short answer:

[Here](https://medium.com/@christoph.schranz/set-up-your-own-gpu-based-jupyterlab-e0d45fcacf43) is a Tutorial on how to set up a GPU-based Jupyterlab instance with Docker (which makes the installation faster).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I removed all existing environments and created a new one, which resolved the issue.

(Also, I had to apply the following to get around an issue caused by removed environments:

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2301
)